# What are the assumptions in a Cox Proportional hazards model?

Tags: cox-model, assumptions

- Proportional hazards assumption
- No omitted variables

Any else?

I'm guessing that the usual assumptions about residuals are captured in the PH assumption?

Comment: Are you asking only what the assumptions are? If this is the case, maybe just a google search or checking some texts on Cox PH models would be faster. Or, are you asking for an explanation of these assumptions? In that case, could you be a little more specific?